# Disable middle-CLICK on laptop?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I just got a new laptop, and it's great. However, in Google Chrome, middle-clicking on a tab closes it, and my middle-click is activated by tapping with two fingers. Unfortunately, recognition of this gesture isn't that great and I end up accidentally closing tabs a lot - and, as my luck would have it, they're usually important.

I absolutely *need* the scroll wheel though. How can I disable a middle-click, which I never use in the first place, but keep the scrolling functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on the laptop manufacturer and if there is some third-party software installed for your trackpad and mouse buttons. I would go looking through your computer's control panel and find the mouse settings in there.

If there is another settings application to manage your specific manufacturer's mousepad, you might find it in there too. Scroll through the available options until you find something that can help with your "middle-click" problems.